# updown control in wpf

Tags: wpf, controls, updown

I want to use a Similar control like domainUPDown control in my wpf application.
How to do the using infragistic or any other way.

I need a control like a textbox with up and down button.

How to do it?
That is ok, but i need tat up and down button for mouse click

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

With Infragistics use the `XamNumericEditor` control. The Up and Down arrow keys make the value change.